# Preventing descendants from overriding method

Tags: c++, private, protected, descendant

In C++ (11/14/17, I don't care), I have a base class `B` which exposes method `x` as `protected`.

In class `D1`, which derives from `B`, I want to prevent further descendants (of `D1`) from calling `x()`.  Now, if I were overriding `x` in `D1`, I would simply mark it as `final`.

But, what if `D1` does not override `x()`, yet `D1` still wants to hide it from descendants?  How can I do that?

Comment: Overriding the method, mark it final and call the base class implementation.

Comment: Sounds like you should rethink your model. You’re asking how to subvert the very reason inheriting exists. To provide an is-a relationship.  Instead of inheritance use containment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that?

By changing the program and overriding `x` in `D1`. You can just delegate to the base class version by calling it.

Comment: How do you 'delegate to the base class version'?   Are you saying override it in D1 anyways, and just the ancestor class?

Comment: @TSG you mean 'just call'?  Yes, he said that explicitly.  The compiler will probably optimise the whole thing away, especially if you enable link time optimisation.